# Authorize.net CIM: Creating customer profile without a billing address

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am trying to create a customer profile on the **live** gateway for CIM, however I get rejected with Error: *"E00027 There is one or more missing or invalid required fields"*. This is my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <merchantAuthentication>
      <name>-removed-</name>
      <transactionKey>-removed-</transactionKey>
   </merchantAuthentication>
   <profile>
      <description>Anush (4f293e17536e86bc66000000)</description>
      <email>anush@foobar.com</email>
      <paymentProfiles>
         <billTo>
            <firstName />
            <lastName />
            <company />
            <address />
            <city />
            <state />
            <zip>94111</zip>
            <country />
         </billTo>
         <payment>
            <creditCard>
               <cardNumber>-removed-</cardNumber>
               <expirationDate>2016-12</expirationDate>
               <cardCode>-removed-</cardCode>
            </creditCard>
         </payment>
      </paymentProfiles>
   </profile>
   <validationMode>liveMode</validationMode>
</createCustomerProfileRequest>
```

and this is the response which says "There is one or more missing or invalid required fields"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createCustomerProfileResponse xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <messages>
      <resultCode>Error</resultCode>
      <message>
         <code>E00027</code>
         <text>There is one or more missing or invalid required fields.</text>
      </message>
   </messages>
   <customerPaymentProfileIdList />
   <customerShippingAddressIdList />
   <validationDirectResponseList>
      <string>3,1,290,There is one or more missing or invalid required fields.,,P,0,none,Test transaction for ValidateCustomerPaymentProfile.,0.00,CC,auth_only,,,,,,,,94111,,,,anush@xola.com,,,,,,,,,0.00,0.00,0.00,FALSE,none,F68A9C87C1E1472521704EF38C21F647,,,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX1234,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,</string>
   </validationDirectResponseList>
</createCustomerProfileResponse>
```

Error code **290** in the response indicates I'm missing AVS (address) information (from [the documentation](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=4_TransResponse.6.4.html)). I've got the zip code, but I don't have the billing address. How do I create a customer profile without specifying a billing address?

All this has worked while in developer mode on the sandbox, but it seems to fail on the live gateway. Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks

Rushi

Answer (score 2):

You must include ZIP and Address into PaymentProfile.

Comment: Somehow I was able to create the payment profile without the zip or address, but I can't update it. Are the required fields different for insert vs update?

Comment: 6+ years later, same question.... I can create but not update.....